# How to select centroid of multiple nearby points with same attribute

Tags: postgis, centroids, multipoint

This question is very similar to [#131823](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131823/merge-multiple-bus-stops-with-same-name), that is not solved yet.

I want to merge several points like bus stops into one single point in the centroid of all selected points. The bus stops have a attribute "name". The problem is that these names are not necessarily unique worldwide, so there needs to be a spatial limit if several points can be combined to a MultiPoint. This done, we can calculate the centroid with PostGIS: http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Centroid.html

How can we solve this problem with Postgis functions?

Comment: This page has some interesting leads: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11567/spatial-clustering-with-postgis

Comment: that's old doc page by the new docs are at - http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Centroid.html

Answer (score 5):

If you have access to [PostGIS 2.2rc1](http://www.postgis.net/2015/09/24/postgis-2.2.0rc1), you can use [ST_ClusterWithin](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/ST_ClusterWithin.html) to group together points that are no more than a specified distance from another point with the same name.  The query would look something like this:

```
SELECT name, ST_Centroid(clustr), ST_NumGeometries(clustr) AS num_points FROM
    (SELECT name, unnest(ST_ClusterWithin(geom, 0.01)) AS clustr FROM points
     GROUP BY name) sq;
```

where `0.01` is the tolerance distance.

With PostGIS 2.1 or earlier, the approaches used to solve [this problem](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/94203/18189) could potentially be useful - you'd just replace the intersection tests with distance tests.

Comment: PostGIS 2.2.0 should be out next week.